# How to avoid a selection from an SQL-database, if certain values match

Tags: mysql

I have a normalized database, where a superior table contains different products and a subordinated table characteristics. The subordinate table is linked to the superior table by a foreign key. This means that there may be several occurrences of one and the same characteristic_id (= foreign key) in the subordinate table if several characteristics match the properties of a product, e.g.

```
Superior table  (product_main_table):

product_id      product_name            
23          apple   
24          orange

25          strawberry      

Subordinate table (product_characteristics):

characteristic_id   product_name            characteristic

23          apple               green           
23          apple               sweet   
23          apple               small   
23          apple               american    
24          orange              orange          
24          orange              sourly  
24          orange              big 

24          orange              african 

25          strawberry          red

25          strawberry          sweet
```

I have an html-form to read out the data and there should also be a possibility to search for all products that DO NOT match certain characteristics.
However, this does not work. When I enter the following request:

```
SELECT DISTINCT main.product_name 
FROM product_main_table main, product_characteristics prodchar 
WHERE prodchar.characteristic != 'sweet'
```

the result is 'apple', 'orange' and 'strawberry', wheresas it should be 'orange', only. The other two products are selected of course, because they have other characteristics than 'sweet' that are selected.

I would be more than happy, if the solution would fit into my general SQL-request

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT $selection FROM $tabelle WHERE $masterarray";
```

where `$selection, $tabelle` and `$masterarray` get their contents from the html-entries.

How do I have to make my where-statement, so that a product is not selected, if it contains a single characteristic that should not be present?

Comment: You need one more condition. add main.product_name=sub_ord.product_name :)

Comment: If you had another field in your characteristics database for category (color, taste, etc), then you could do WHERE prodchar.category = 'taste' AND prodchar.characteristic != 'sweet'

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :) However, the result is the same as before.

Comment: Thanks Stevish, but the characteristics can be numerous for any product and therefore I would need a general solution with variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7fd63b/5

```
SELECT pmt.product_name
FROM product_characteristics pc
JOIN product_main_table pmt
ON pmt.product_id = pc.characteristic_id
GROUP BY characteristic_id
HAVING SUM(characteristic IN ('sweet'))=0
```

Comment: Thanks Alex! Your solution brings the right result! :) Is it possible to integrate the JOIN-Statement in my Select-query with the Where-Statement? Because, in parallel, multiple other queries should be possible.

Comment: Alex, a Problem with this solution just occured: if there is only one value that should not be present, it works perfect! However, if there are further values added (e.g. HAVING SUM(characteristic IN ('sweet, big, red'))=0) the list becomes longer and there are values, that shouldn´t be selected.

Comment: I can not see any problem if you add more values in `IN` array. please provide any proof: sample of row data and list of values that should be excluded.

Comment: Thank you Alex, I got it! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @characteristic='sweet,sour,bland';
...
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(prodchar.characteristic, @characteristic) = 0
```

or per your requested example

```
$sql = "SET @characteristic='sweet,sour,bland';SELECT DISTINCT $selection FROM $tabelle WHERE FIND_IN_SET(prodchar.characteristic, @characteristic) = 0;";
```

you can also use php string concatenation to echo in your variable into the $sql variable if needed.

Comment: thanks! But 'sweet' was only an example. This should be variable so that one or multiple characteristics could be excluded

Comment: edited give this a shot it should get you what you need

Comment: just make sure you feed your html fields get comma separated for the SET variable

Comment: Unfortunately, I got an error because of the "@". Where do I have to write this Statement, Jay?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the NOT IN function:

`... WHERE prodchar.characteristic NOT IN (SELECT characteristic FROM product_characteristics WHERE name = main.product_name)`

Answer (score 0):

You could do some thing like

`SELECT DISTINCT prodchar.product_name 
FROM product_characteristics prodchar 
WHERE prodchar.product_name not in (select product_name from product_characteristics
                            where characteristic in ('sweet'))`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce6f6/7

Performance would be bad, Try using Joins. [Join vs. sub-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query)